# Is it possible to make the hover and click effects programmatically on a echarts sunburst (Angular)?

Tags: angular, echarts, sunburst-diagram

Is it possible to make the hover and click effects programmatically on a echarts sunburst (Angular)? Like, from a custom function in my typescript file, I can apply the sunburst click or hover effect:

```
customFunction(labelName: string): void {
 this.chart.dispatchAction({
      type: 'hover/click',
      seriesIndex: 0,
      name: labelName,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hover labelName :

```js
this.chart.dispatchAction({
   type: 'highlight',
   seriesIndex: 0,
   name: labelName,
});
```

Comment: Yes, but it will not highlight the sunburst as when you hover a section of it. It should hover labelName and childrens of labelName

Comment: It just depends on the rule you chose for `series.emphasis.focus`. If you set it to 'self', it will indeed just hover labelName. But if you have let `focus` to its default value or if you've put it manually to 'descendant', it will behave exactly as you want (i.e. hover labelName and childrens of labelName).